# Calling another cpp function in templated Rcpp function

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm trying to create some sort of sapply function in Rcpp, which works as follows:

- `apply_cpp_fun(x, fun, ...)` function takes two arguments: vector of any type `x`, and any cpp function `fun`, plus optional arguments needed in `fun` (eg. `bool na_rm`). In example I keep it simple, just `x` and `fun`.
- I want `fun` to be applied on selected elements of `x` (possible `fun` outputs - bool, int, double, string). I wan't apply to be called multiple times inside `apply_cpp_fun`.
- Output of `apply_cpp_fun` is a vector of any type dependent on `fun` output (can be different than `x`). `fun` is called n-times, to produce each element of output vector `res`.

I'm trying to achieve this by but each time output turns to be a `Rcpp::List` instead of `Rcpp::Vector<double>`.

Here is a code, I didn't write whole body of `apply_cpp_fun` to keep example shorter. As you can see, even if I pass `<double>function`, template gets Vector described as `double (*)(Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>)`.

```cpp
  #include <Rcpp.h>

  double cpp_sum(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
    int n = x.size();
    double cursum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      cursum += x(i);
    }

     return cursum;
  }

  template <int ITYPE, typename ftype>
  Rcpp::Vector<Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits<ftype>::rtype>
  apply_cpp_fun(Rcpp::Vector<ITYPE>& x,
                ftype fun) {

    int n = x.size();
    double xx = 5.0;

    # typenames
    Rcpp::Rcout << "type of xx: " << demangle(typeid(xx).name()).c_str() << std::endl;
    Rcpp::Rcout << "function type: " << demangle(typeid(ftype).name()).c_str() << std::endl;
    const int OTYPE = Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits<ftype>::rtype;
    Rcpp::Rcout << "SEXP type: " << OTYPE << std::endl;

    # apply fun n-times
    Rcpp::Vector<OTYPE> res(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      res(i) = fun(x);
    }

    return res;  # return vector
  }

  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  SEXP cumsum_cpp(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
    return apply_cpp_fun(x, cpp_sum);
  }
```

Call function to see result

```r
cumsum_cpp(as.numeric(1:2))
# type of xx: double
# function type: double (*)(Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>)
# SEXP type: 19
# [[1]]
# NULL
#
# [[2]]
# NULL
```

How to fix this to keep applier flexible for input type and output?
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can give the `RCPP_RETURN_VECTOR` macro a try. There have been several questions about it here on SO.

Comment: Thanks, I will explore this possibility

Comment: To get the return type of the function you will need https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach to implementing `apply_cpp_fun` uses the trick of capturing the output type of the function to be applied using `decltype` and converting it to the appropriate SEXP type with `Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits<T>::rtype`. If this is captured as a `constexpr int` then it can be used as the template parameter for creating an `Rcpp:Vector` of the appropriate type.

The upside of doing it this way is that you don't need to pass any template parameters to `apply_cpp_fun`.

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

template<typename Func, typename Input>
SEXP apply_cpp_fun(Input& v, Func f)
{
  int n = v.size();
  constexpr int t = Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits<decltype(f(v, n))>::rtype;
  Rcpp::Vector<t> result(n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) result(i) = f(v, i);
  return result;
}
```

Suppose we have the following functions to be applied:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]

Rcpp::String as_string(Rcpp::NumericVector const& x, int i) {
  return std::to_string(x[i]);
}

double as_numeric(Rcpp::NumericVector const& x, int i) {
  return x[i];
}
```

Then we can apply them using `apply_cpp_fun` and export to R like this:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector test1_tmpl(Rcpp::NumericVector x) 
{
  return apply_cpp_fun(x, as_numeric);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::StringVector test2_tmpl(Rcpp::NumericVector x) 
{
  return apply_cpp_fun(x, as_string);
}
```

Now in R:

```
test1_tmpl(1:5)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5

test2_tmpl(1:5)
# [1] "1.000000" "2.000000" "3.000000" "4.000000" "5.000000"
```

### Note

Although the OP accepted my original answer of working with `std::` types and simply passing them in and out using Rcpp's native conversions, it was pointed out by @KonradRudolph that this involves unnecessary copies. After some further clarifications and suggestions by the OP, I changed my answer to the above with the OP's permission, and have used the examples given in the OP's own answer.

Comment: Thanks, In your example output vector type is taken from x but I need it to be dependent on function output. There can be a case where input is a numeric vector and output is a string vector (concatenating).

Comment: In that case, the second argument to the template function needs to be a pointer to a function whose type is calculated at compile time. See my edit, which does what you want.

Comment: Nice! This gives me almost complete path to the solution I need. Question: what if callable function have more than one argument? For example: `std::string nth_string(std::vector<double> x, int i) return std::to_string(x[i]);`. How to pass function when `U(*f)(std::vector<T>)` has single argument?

Comment: You can overload the template to accept another parameter. Example added.

Comment: Doesn’t this code force (costly) copies though, which OP’s code doesn’t have because it doesn’t need to move between `std::vector` and `Rcpp::Vector`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes. This is not optimised for performance, though the output type is an atomic element, so copying usually isn't that expensive. It would be well worth it if you are going to do a lot of processing in C++. It depends on the use case.

Comment: “This is not optimised for performance” — Then why use Rcpp at all? ;-) You say that the output type is atomic but given OP’s use-case I very much doubt it. The output is a non-atomic vector of potentially large size.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the OP specifically says in his question that the possible function outputs are bools, doubles and strings. How are these non-atomic vectors of potentially large size?

Comment: @Allan What OP meant was clearly “[non-atomic *vectors* of] bool, int, double, string”. Just look at the function name.

Comment: @KonradRudolph @AllanCameron I've just updated description to clarify a bit. `apply_rcpp_fun` should return a vector, where each element is an output of `fun`. Functions exported have some sort of `sapply(x, function(xx) fun(x))` in the body.

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/structRcpp_1_1traits_1_1r__sexptype__traits.html) states that `r_sexptype_traits` is a

> template that returns the SEXP type that is appropriate for the type T, this is allways VECSXP (lists) unless it is specialized

So. *Is* it specialised for function pointer types? Not as far as I can see, and it’s not clear what the specialisation would return: You seem to want it to return a function’s return type — but that’s not what this metafunction does. Rather, it performs a mapping between C++ and R SEXP types (in other words, the mapping from the [`SEXPTYPES` table](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPTYPEs-1)).

As noted in a comment by Ralf, you need [`std::result_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) or, if you’re using C++17, `std::invoke_result`:

```
template <typename T>
using RcppVec = Rcpp::Vector<Rcpp::traits::r_sexptype_traits<T>::rtype>;

template <int ITYPE, typename FTYPE>
auto apply_cpp_fun(Rcpp::Vector<ITYPE> const& x, FTYPE fun) ->
    RcppVec<typename std::result_of<FTYPE>::type>
{
    …
}
```

Comment: Your solution seems to be optimal for my needs, but I have a trouble with calling `apply_cpp_fun` as I got the substitution error. I've put your proposition into my example and can't compile anymore - [my gist](https://gist.github.com/gogonzo/f1360c4e1c13143c261afcecfa34ca01)

Answer (score 1):

Other solution is to add another template parameter specifying the output type. As output is known before calling `apply_cpp_fun`, one can use additional parameter instead of inherit type from the function passed in argument. One needs only to add `<int OTYPE, ...>` at the beginning of template parameter list, and then call `apply_cpp_fun<SEXPTYPE_no>(...)` with relevant SEXP-type number from the [table](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPTYPEs-1).

**Functions to be applied**

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]

Rcpp::String as_string(Rcpp::NumericVector const& x, int i) {
  return std::to_string(x[i]);
}

double as_numeric(Rcpp::NumericVector const& x, int i) {
  return x[i];
}
```

**Applier**

```cpp
template <int OTYPE, int ITYPE, typename FTYPE>
Rcpp::Vector<OTYPE> apply_cpp_fun(Rcpp::Vector<ITYPE> const& x, FTYPE fun) {
  int n = x.size();
  Rcpp::Vector<OTYPE>   res(n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    res[i] = fun(x, i);
  }

  return res;
}
```

**Exported functions**

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector test1_tmpl(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
  return apply_cpp_fun<14>(x, as_numeric);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::StringVector test2_tmpl(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
  return apply_cpp_fun<16>(x, as_string);
}
```

**R output**

```r
test1_tmpl(1:5)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5

test2_tmpl(1:5)
# [1] "1.000000" "2.000000" "3.000000" "4.000000" "5.000000"
```

---

Solution is optimal in terms of performance as it doesn't cast any type nor copy object - same speed as no-templated Rcpp function.

**Function to be compared**

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::StringVector test2(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  Rcpp::StringVector   res(n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    res[i] = as_string(x, i);
  }

  return res;
}
```

Benchmark

```r
x <- runif(10000)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  test2_tmpl(x),
  test2(x),
  times = 1000L
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  test2_tmpl(x) 3.456110 3.620221 4.367001 3.870608 4.469028 34.37925  1000
#       test2(x) 3.439571 3.617877 4.313639 3.851150 4.302168 77.42430  1000
```

Comment: this problem has been driving me nuts for the last few days. I have eventually found a way for you to avoid having to pass the template parameters to the function. See my updated edit, which will work as a drop-in replacement for your "applier" in this answer, provided you drop the <SEXPTYPE> template parameters from your exported functions. With your permission, I would like to update my answer using your own examples to make this the actual answer.